# Multi-line button groups in bootstrap 4

Tags: button, bootstrap-4

In boostrap 4, it is possible to have button groups.

Horizontals:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

and verticals, using the class `btn-group-vertical`.

Is it possible to obtain in a nice way a **3x3 button array**, such as in a numerical pad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest the btn-group inside btn-group vertical and adjust the borders using the utility classes...

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-bottom-0 rounded-0">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-bottom-0">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-bottom-0 rounded-0">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-bottom-0 rounded-0">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-bottom-0">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-bottom-0 rounded-0">6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">9</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/yZprmIVhl8

Answer (score 1):

How about just using multiple button groups?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
</div><br>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">6</button>
</div><br>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">9</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I tried so far. It is ok, but the rounded corners and the border-top/border-bottom touch. I believed there was a method to do it